# How to create a sorting index in C#?

Tags: c#, sorting

I have an array of values and I want to create a sorting index, i.e. an auxiliary array of integers that lists the element in sorted order by indirect addressing.

In other words,

```
I <= J -> Value[Index[I]] <= Value[Index[J]]
```

How can I define a comparator for the `Sort` method to achieve that ? The array of values must remain unchanged.

Comment: The implementation might require a different approach if the array is very large or when the objects are mutable (or both). In these cases it might be worth it to sort on insert.

Comment: The array is large and holds scalars. What do you mean by "sort on insert" ?

Comment: Sort on insert would mean that you insert the items in such a way that the array is always sorted. That way insertion is more expensive but there is no need to sort the array anymore (if the items are immutable)

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd: I am working with arrays so insertion can take linear time. Thus the whole insertion process could be O(N²), which is completely unacceptable. I don't see how this could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to build such an index I see is to use LINQ:

```
var Index = Enumerable.Range(0, Value.Length).OrderBy(i => Value[i]).ToArray();
```

or if you insist on using `Array.Sort`, then you can use the overloads that accept [`Comparison<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate:

```
var Index = new int[Value.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < Index.Length; i++)
    Index[i] = i;
Array.Sort(Index, (a, b) => Comparer<Value_Type>.Default.Compare(Value[a], Value[b]));
```

where the `Value_Type` is the type of the `Value` array elements.

Another option (IMO the best) is to create a reusable generic comparer like this:

```
public static class Comparers
{
    public static IComparer<int> CreateIndexComparer<T>(this IReadOnlyList<T> source, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        return new ListIndexComparer<T>(source, comparer);
    }

    private sealed class ListIndexComparer<T> : Comparer<int>
    {
        readonly IReadOnlyList<T> list;
        readonly IComparer<T> comparer;
        public ListIndexComparer(IReadOnlyList<T> list, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
        {
            this.list = list;
            this.comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
        }
        public override int Compare(int x, int y)
        {
            return x != y ? comparer.Compare(list[x], list[y]) : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it with the `Array.Sort` overloads that accept `IComparer<T>`:

```
Array.Sort(Index, Value.CreateIndexComparer());
```

Comment: Yep, I indeed prefer the `Sort` version for efficiency reasons (my array holds a million values). Seems that your second option is what I need. I was wondering how to pass the array `Value` and I didn't think of lambdas.

Comment: Mh, the "Sort" solution keeps saying "Error 1 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Array' because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: Hmm, `Index` is `int[]`, right? My test is hitting either [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzw8611x(v=vs.110).aspx) or [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf(v=vs.110).aspx). Here is the test `var Value = new[] { "C", "A", "D", "B" };
var Index = Enumerable.Range(0, Value.Length).ToArray();
Array.Sort(Index, Value.CreateIndexComparer());`

Comment: I am refering to the second solution, with a lambda.

Comment: In the end it works with the following syntax (the compiler seems to have trouble resolving some overloads): `Array.Sort(Index, (P, Q) => Y[P].CompareTo(Y[Q]));`

Comment: Yeah, that should work too. I just didn't know what is the type of the element of the value array, hence if it has `CompareTo` method or not. With my string test both work - `Array.Sort(Index, (a, b) => Comparer<string>.Default.Compare(Value[a], Value[b]));`